How to remove/disable Use Client Integration features from each permission/role definition on a SharePoint Online site using PowerShell
I am creating a site script which allows a SharePoint Online admin create a site from a site script template. Further in the process an Azure Runbook is triggered and at this point I need it to deselect the User Client Integration feature within each permission.
I have tried:
$roleDefinitions = Get-PnPRoleDefinition
Write-Host "Starting loop to remove Client Integration features"
# Loop through each role definition and remove Client Integration features
foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleDefinitions) {
    Write-Host "Starting if"
    if ($roleDefinition.BasePermissions.Has()) {
        $roleDefinition.BasePermissions.Clear([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::UseClientIntegration)
        $roleDefinition.Update()
        $context.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host "Removed Client Integration from role: $($roleDefinition.Name)"
    }
}

I have also tried:
# Get the existing permission level
$existingPermissionLevel = Get-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "YourPermissionLevelName"

# Create a new BasePermissions object
$newBasePermissions = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.BasePermissions

# Add permissions to the new BasePermissions object
$permissionsToAdd = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::ViewListItems, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::AddListItems, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::EditListItems, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::DeleteListItems, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::ApproveItems, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::OpenItems, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::ViewVersions, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::DeleteVersions, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::CancelCheckout, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::ManagePersonalViews, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::ManageLists, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::ViewFormPages, `
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PermissionKind]::Open

foreach ($permission in $permissionsToAdd) {
    $newBasePermissions.Set($permission)
}

I've also looked at the top google results here:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/06/update-permissions-in-custom-permission-level-using-powershell.html
And here:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/01/sharepoint-online-update-permission-level-using-powershell.html
I've also read the official documentation from Microsoft, and well, you can probably guess whether it was helpful or not!
I've also tried Copilot and it keeps sending me round in circles.
Has anyone done this in the past and got a snippet they can share please?

There doesn't seem to a way to directly change the permission levels so I had to make a fairly convoluted process:
$roleDefinitions = Get-PnPRoleDefinition

foreach ($role in $roleDefinitions) {
    # Create a new custom role definition by copying the existing one
    $newRoleName = "Custom_" + $role.Name
    # Clone the existing permission levels excluding Client Int.:
  Add-PnPRoleDefinition -RoleName $newRoleName -Clone $role -Exclude UseClientIntegration
    # Remove the original role definition
    Remove-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity $role.Name -Force
}
# Get the new role definitions:
$newRoleDefinitions = Get-PnPRoleDefinition
# Rename each permission to remove the "Custom_"
foreach ($newRole in $newRoleDefinitions) {
 Set-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity $newRole.Name -NewRoleName $newRole.Name.TrimStart("Custom_")

}
# Remove the erroneously created permission levels:
 if($role.Name -eq "Custom_Limited Access" -or "Custom_Web-Only Limited Access" -or "Custom_Full Control") {
            Remove-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "Custom_Limited Access" -Force
            Remove-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "Custom_Web-Only Limited Access" -Force
            Remove-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "Custom_Full Control" -Force
             Set-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "ntribute" -NewRoleName "Contribute" 
#Not sure why earlier in the script it changes Contribute to "ntribute" but i'm having to rename it here.
        }

Hope this helps someone out there.

If it is just for a certain SharePoint site, you can make it directly in the UI interface.

Hi - its for any newly created SharePoint site (I'm adding it to a site template script). So, how would I make it directly in the UI interface?
